# Data Update in Slick Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid, with about 100 rows.
Its data is refreshed in 5 seconds, but it is disturbing at each update the scroll is reset.
I have tried to use dataview and dataview.refresh() but this time no change is reflecte to grid.

Here what I tried at each refresh:

```
mapMemoryTableDataView.beginUpdate();
mapMemoryTableDataView.setItems(data);
mapMemoryTableDataView.endUpdate();
mapMemoryTableDataView.refresh();

if(mapMemoryTableGrid == null)
    mapMemoryTableGrid = new Slick.Grid("#datatableMap1", mapMemoryTableDataView, columns, options);

mapMemoryTableGrid.updateRow(1)
mapMemoryTableGrid.render()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have called the following

```
 mapMemoryTableDataView.beginUpdate();
    mapMemoryTableDataView.setItems(data);
    mapMemoryTableDataView.endUpdate();
    mapMemoryTableDataView.refresh();
    for (var i = 0; i < olist.length; i++) {
        mapMemoryTableGrid.updateRow(i)
    }
```

invalidate and refresh did not cure my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely try the `invalidate`method

```
grid.invalidate();
```

From personal experience, all you need to do to refresh the grid is to use the `invalidate` method, provided on the grid. This updates everything and also preserves the scroll.

And by refresh, do you mean you are replacing the data, or updating certain rows?

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
gridItems.invalidate();
gridItems.render();
```

invalidate: mean nead to validate which row you want - in this case: no parameter row id = all row

Answer (score 0):

I have called the following code:

```
        mapMemoryDataView.beginUpdate();
        mapMemoryDataView.setItems(pointsRows, "id");
        mapMemoryDataView.endUpdate();
        mapMemoryDataView.syncGridSelection(pointsGrid, false);

        for (var i = 0; i < pointsRows.length; i++) {
            mapMemoryTableGrid.updateRow(i);
        }

        mapMemoryTableGrid.invalidate();
        mapMemoryTableGrid.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
    events[v_current_row_num].field_id = v_new_field_id;
    events_grid.updateRowCount();
    events_grid.render();
```

I am using different grid and view names, but the concept revolved around calling updateRowCount and render functions.